# Unable to set up Android Target in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator

I am constantly getting this error when I go to Preferences -> Android -> and then try to browse for my SDK Location.

```
Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK '/Applications/eclipse/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/'.
```

I am able to run the Emulators if I manually go into 
/Applications/eclipse/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/android
and open up the terminal application but only then can I open the SDK and AVD manager.

How do I set my eclipse up to set both the Target correctly and open the SDK and AVD manager natively?

Answer (score -2):

select the sub folder ...that would do the trick