# Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I am doing **Android Development** using Eclipse. I have downloaded all the required software, but I am having the same problem as discussed in ["*Unable to set up Android Target in Eclipse*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384328/unable-to-set-up-android-target-in-eclipse). Now I do **not** find the **solution of the problem** on that **discussion** so let me rewrite the problem again,

When I load Eclipse and create a new Android project, it keeps on waiting for the ADT to load. To figure out what is wrong I went to preferences and tried to put the location of the ADT I created in it but it keeps giving me this error when I put the address of ADT,

> Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK 'E:\Documents and
> Settings\me\android-sdks'..

How can this issue be resolved?

I created the folder tools manually, now I am getting this error:

```
[2011-12-24 15:23:56 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: E:\Documents and Settings\me\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe E:\Documents and Settings\me\android-sdks\tools\hprof-conv.exe E:\Documents and Settings\me\android-sdks\tools\traceview.bat 
[2011-12-24 15:42:06 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: E:\Documents and Settings\me\.android\platform-tools\adb.exe E:\Documents and Settings\me\.android\tools\hprof-conv.exe E:\Documents and Settings\me\.android\tools\traceview.bat
```

Comment: Did you install the SDK with the All-in-one Executable? http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r16-windows.exe ??

Comment: Try uninstalling the blackberry development kit in case you have that installed. I had that installed, after uninstalling that I could able to update the ADT.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you install Eclipse properly then:

1. Start Eclipse
2. From the menu bar, select Window > Preferences > Android
3. For Android location, browse the folder in which you install Android SDKs.
4. In Android SDKs folder, rename the folder `platforms-tools` to `tools`.
5. Select the folder Android SDKs through Preferences dialog box.

Comment: This was a welcome first step because without it I could not bring up the Eclipse/Window/SDK Manager. After following these 5 steps I removed all 22.x installs using the "already installed" link in the SDK Manager. Then fully installed 23.x files via the SDK Manager. Back in business - thanks BALJINDER for the first part and Kikiwa for the conflict resolution part.

Comment: for me there are two folders, "platform-tools" & "tools". In this case what can I do???

Comment: Its perfect . Working fine

Comment: If Eclipse gives you another error like `"Cannot find 'emulator' inside 'tools' folder"`, then just create a blank file called emulator in the tools folder. It's not ideal, but it works, and you can still build your apps properly. (Just install the app manually)

Answer (score 15):

If I get you correctly you have just downloaded Android sdk and want to configure it working with Eclipse. I think you miss one step from the installation of the sdk: 
 1) you download it 
 2) you extract it somewhere
 3) then go to the specified directory and start AndroidManager (or was it just android??). There you specify you need platform-tools and the manager will configure that for you. This will also provide you with the 'adb' executable which is crucial for the Android developement.

After that you install ADT (which I think you already did) and from Eclipse preferences -> Android options you get a place to specify where your android-sdk is. If you specify it after you did the 'step 3' you should be good to go.

I am not 100% sure I got it correctly and what your state is, so please forgive me if my comment is irrelevant. If I am wrong I will be happy to help if you provide some more details.

Something I am completely sure is that you shouldn't need to create the folder 'tools' by yourself.

PS: The description I gave is for newer versions of android sdk, but if you are encountering a problem with older version I will recommend you to start from scratch with newer version. It shouldn't take you that long time.

Comment: Thanks! The key part for me was "Eclipse preferences -> Android options you get a place to specify where your android-sdk is." It all worked then!

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen due to the bad unzipping process of SDK.It Happend to me.
Dont use inbuilt windows unzip process.
use WINRAR software for unzipping sdk

Answer (score 0):

By default it looks for the SDK tools in "C:\Documents and Settings\user\android-sdks". Some times we install it at another location. So you just have to select the correct path and it will done.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when the SDK tools installation was failed during the initial setup. To resolution is to download SDK tools from [Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#ExistingIDE)

- Expand "USE AN EXISTING IDE" section and download standalone SDK tools
- Choose your destination as (%HOMEPATH%\android-sdks)
- Now start Android-SDKs folder and run SDK manager

Answer (score 0):

If you get the "Failed to find DDMS files..." do this:

1. Open eclipse
2. Open install new software
3. Click "Add..." -> type in (e.g.) "Android_over_HTTP" and in address put "http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/".

Don't be alarmed that its not https, this helps to fetch stuff over http. This trick helped me to resolve the issue on MAC, I believe that this also should work on Windows / Linux

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using Ubuntu. Where the was two directories one was **/android-sdks** 
and **/android-sdk-linux**. I used the second one it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to remove the Eclipse ADT plugin via menu "Help > About Eclipse SDK > Installation Details". Eclipse will restart.

Next go to Menu "Help > Install New Software", then add the ADT plugin url "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse" (or select the existing link from the dropdown).

This will re-install the latest ADT, including the DDMS files.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a simple case of specifying the path to the 'sdk' subfolder rather than the top level folder.

In my case I needed to input

`/Users/Myusername/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk`

instead of

`/Users/Myusername/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321`