# Serious problems in Configuring Android SDK with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-emulator

I am having serious problems in Configuring ADT with Eclipse. I am using Windows 7 Home Premium version.

The Eclipse (64 bit) that I am using is:

```
Eclipse Classic 3.7.1 
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110615-0604
```

Java code runs without any problem in this Eclipse. For running Android:

at first, I went into Eclipse-> Help menu and then Install New Software.
Clicked Add, named it ADT and for location used: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse.

The new window that appears, I have clicked all of those boxes and choose Next. Upto this point, everything is OK, ADT is installed and I am be asked to restart Eclipse.  When Eclipse launches, a new window appears and asks me to either install the Android Software Development Kit (SDK) or choose an existing SDKs location. I chose to install Android Software Development Kit (SDK) (I checked all the options). I have set SDK location to: C:\My_Workspace\Android_SDK. After everything finishes I see two errors in the Eclipse console:

```
[2012-01-02 14:29:37 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: C:\My_Workspace\eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\platform-tools\adb.exe C:\My_Workspace\eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\tools\hprof-conv.exe C:\My_Workspace\eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\tools\traceview.bat

[2012-01-02 14:30:47 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: C:\My_Workspace\Android_SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe C:\My_Workspace\Android_SDK\tools\hprof-conv.exe C:\My_Workspace\Android_SDK\tools\traceview.bat
```

Note, I have tried to install the SDK at the default location given by Eclipse. But I see the same errors.

If I restart Eclipse an error appears saying: 
"Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK 'C:\My_Workspace\Android_SDK\'".

If I click into Window ->Android SDK manager, I get another error message saying:
"location of the Android SDK has not been setup in the preference."

If I go Window->Preference->Android, I see that, the SDK location is set to "C:\My_Workspace\Android_SDK"
But on top, there is an error message saying, "Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK 'C:\My_Workspace\Android_SDK\'."

Inside the C:\My_Workspace\Android_SDK\ folder I see only two sub folders:
add-ons 
platforms
But there is nothing inside these folders.

Inside "C:\Users\anis_huq.android" folder I see a folder called AVD (contents empty) and file called "ddms".

What is going on? I am confused!

P.S. the post: [Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624003/could-not-find-folder-tools-inside-sdk)  does not help my cause.

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved after 1.5 days of work. This is how:

When you get the error:

```
[2012-01-02 14:29:37 - DDMS] DDMS files not found:
C:\My_Workspace\eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\platform-tools\adb.exe
C:\My_Workspace\eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\tools\hprof-conv.exe 
C:\My_Workspace\eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\tools\traceview.bat

[2012-01-02 14:30:47 - DDMS] DDMS files not found:
C:\My_Workspace\Android_SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe
C:\My_Workspace\Android_SDK\tools\hprof-conv.exe
C:\My_Workspace\Android_SDK\tools\traceview.bat
```

go to the site: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and download, install;
installer_r16-windows.exe

After the installation, you will still see some errors like:

```
Fetching
https:// dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml Failed
to fetch URL
https:// dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml,
reason: peer not authenticated Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL:
https:// dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml Failed
to fetch URL
https:// dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml, reason:
peer not authenticated Done loading packages. Fetching URL:
https:// dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml Failed
to fetch URL
https:// dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml, reason:
peer not authenticated
```

The problem is not so evident from the error messages. We figured that, the HTTPS is actually causing the problem. So, start

Android SDK Manager->Tools->Options and now CHECK the box that says:
`force https://... sources to be fetched using http://`

and then click Packages->Reload.

Everything will be installed as your wish! Now run Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Android and set the location of the newly installed Android SDK (i.e. the location of "android-sdk" folder). And you are ready to go.

1.5 days wasted for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try [installing the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) separately first. Then get Eclipse configured appropriately. You might need to run the SDK installer as an administrator in order to have some permissions set up appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. This ones helped me. Has Google changed the Eclipse logo and stuff and call it ADT? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading ad installing the Android SDK manually, then pointing Eclipse to that location?  You will need to run "SDK Manager.exe" to download at least one platform...

Also... Make sure you don't have any spaces in the path to the Android SDK and Eclipse or you might get strange errors.

Answer (score 0):

In the last time I face all the time with such strange errors. The solution in these cases usually is the following.

I guess that you use JDK 7. Android SDK is not compatible with JDK 7. You have to use JDK 6 or JDK 5 (but 5 is too old). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I have installed JDK 7. I will get rid of it and install JDK 6 now. Lets see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Remember the path where you install the android sdk and provide the correct location at window>preferences>android. On my windows 7 system the location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk. After you provide location in preferences, click apply.

Answer (score 0):

I had this too and just solved it. For me, it turned out that I didn't have all the libraries like the tools package.

Other things to keep in mind that helped me overcome related errors:

```
1) When giving urls from where to download, if the https doesn't work, try http
2) Run your eclipse as administrator if u r running it from Windows 7 - that will help you avoid permissions problems.
```