# ADT bundle error: "Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK"

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I'm running adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030 on Windows7.  I've been using it for several months.  Yesterday, I found that my Develop folder, which includes the unzipped ADT bundle as well as my workspaces, had moved (!) from my login directory (c:/users/tom/) to the "My Documents" folder (c:/users/tom/My Documents).  That was certainly alarming and not something that I can explain, but I've no choice but to scratch my head and move along.  So I copied the Develop folder back where it started.

But now when I start eclipse, it starts as if it's never run before and immediately a popup says, "Android SDK : Location of the Android SDK has not been setup in preferences."  It gives me two choices, "Open Preferences and "Close".  I picked the former, and it throws me into the Preferences:Android form where it wants me to fill in "SDK Location".  I browse to "c"/users/tom/Develop/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-2013103/sdk", but it says "Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK 'C:\Users\tom\Develop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\'." "Apply" and "OK" remain grayed out.

This is similar to [Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624003/could-not-find-folder-tools-inside-sdk), except the apparent solution there does not work.  I've searched with Explorer and I'm pretty sure the tools folders are in that directory tree.

Help!