# Android apps failed to launch after updating Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I created a simple "Hello, World" Android app.
Then I checked for updates in Eclipse. A lot of updates were installed.
After installing them and restarting Eclipse I got an error in my Android app. The main activity page is not loaded and I see the message `Unable to resolve target 'android-16' until the SDK is loaded.`
If I click `Window->Preferences` and navigate to "Android", it shows me `"No target available"`. I remember, that before that, there was something there instead of `"No target available"`.
I found out that during the update file `"adb.exe"` was moved from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`. I tried to change the directory in the properties (`Window->Preferences`) to `...\platform-tools`, but it gave me the message `Could not find folder 'tools' in ...`

The Android SDK manager fails to launch. When I click `Window->Android SDK Manager`, it says `Starting ...` but nothing happens afterwards.

At Stackoverflow I found several questions regarding this problem. BUT none of the solutions worked for me. Here is the list of similar questions solutions to which didn't help me:
[Android Problem: Eclipse cannot find ADB.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361349/android-problem-eclipse-cannot-find-adb-exe) 
[Could not find adb.exe - after upgrade to Android SDK 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375175/could-not-find-adb-exe-after-upgrade-to-android-sdk-2-3) 
[Unable to set up Android Target in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384328/unable-to-set-up-android-target-in-eclipse) 
[Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624003/could-not-find-folder-tools-inside-sdk)

Please help me to solve this problem!

Comment: Change the directory to the sdk directory not the platform-tools directory

Comment: What directory do you mean? For `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk` it doesn't see adb.exe file there...

Comment: If that is your SDK directory then yes. What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Juno.
Even if I copy manually `adb.exe` to that folder, it still shows me `No target available` when I choose that folder with SDK...

Comment: Can you confirm that your SDK directory contains "/platforms/android-*"

Comment: My SDK directory is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`. It contains folders: `platforms`, `platform-tools`, `tools` and some other folders as well as files `AVD Manager.exe`, `SDK Manager.exe`, `SDK Readme.txt` and `uninstall.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you navigate to your SDK directory and launch the SDK Manager and confirm that you have platforms installed in this SDK directory. If not then install them. Then confirm you have properly set the SDK directory in eclipse. Window->Preferences->Android

Comment: If I try to launch it, a black (console) window appears for a very short period of time, then disappears and that's all... So the SDK manager doesn't launch

Comment: Even if you launch it directly from the folder not through eclipse?

Comment: Yes. The same problem. Even if I launch it from Windows Explorer or Far Manager.

Comment: Sounds like you may need to reinstall the SDK if you can't launch the manager.

Answer (score 0):

I completely reinstalled the Android SDK and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Eclipse (if you save the zip as me, only redecompress :) ).
Then set the android sdk path again.